# 'log4net' for trivial console application

Tags: c#, log4net

```
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure();
log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Program));
```

With these two lines my logger is configured to write to the console.

How do I output just to a file instead ?

Comment: By configuring and adding a FileAppender to the BasicConfigurator's Appenders.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html) for log4net?

Comment: read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390668/is-there-a-difference-between-log4net-config-basicconfigurator-configure-and-l

Answer (score 0):

Use the `XmlConfigurator`

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new Uri("path to your file"));
```

Comment: `XmlConfigurator.Configure()` is to read the config from your application config. OP is using `BasicConfigurator.Configure()` to build his configuration from code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use fluent configuration like this :

```
Dim fileappender = New log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender()
fileappender.AppendToFile = True
fileappender.Threshold = log4net.Core.Level.Debug
fileappender.File = "MyLogFile_"
fileappender.DatePattern = "yyyyMMddhhmm"
fileappender.StaticLogFileName = False
fileappender.Layout = New log4net.Layout.SimpleLayout()
fileappender.RollingStyle = log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Date
fileappender.ActivateOptions()
DirectCast(log4net.LogManager.GetRepository(), log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy).Root.AddAppender(fileappender)
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(fileappender)
log.InfoFormat("Hurray. I have configured a rolling file appender via code.")
```

Found this snippet here : http://rajeshsv.blogspot.it/2013/01/configuring-log4net-rolling-file.html

Answer (score 0):

```
  <log4net>
    <!--<Appender for Info and Error logging>-->
    <appender name="LogInfoFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender" >
      <param name="File" value="D:\\InfoMode.txt" /> <!--<Please specify the file with path here for log file>-->
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true"/>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <param name="ConversionPattern"
             value="%-5p – %20C %20M %m%n%n" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="LogInfoFileAppender" />
    </root>
  </log4net>
```

private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

log.Error("Connection Failed");